# How to mass add file extension?

Tags: command-line, filename, batch-rename

My [photo importer](http://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/) moved files from my camera and renamed them, but I forgot to specify that it should keep the file extension. So **I have several folders with hundreds of JPG & AVI files that are all missing their proper extension.**

There aren't that many video files so I can manually rename them either before of after a general mass-rename to JPG.

To make things more complicated, the filenames contain spaces, so I can't just `mv "*" "*.jpg"` because, well, that doesn't work (but that's what I'd do, coming from DOS/Windows).

I know Linux is full of powerful commands. How can I mass-rename files to add a .jpg extension, when those files contain spaces?

<sub>Please don't say "don't use spaces" because that's really not what I'm asking about. Thanks.</sub>

Comment: Okay, I won't tell you to use spaces, but if you change your mind later try `find /PATH/TO/FOLDER -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;` [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709619) which will replace all spaces in files & folders & subfolders for you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Shell globs should work even with spaces in the names if used properly e.g.

```
rename -nv -- 's/$/.jpg/' *
```

or

```
for file in *; do echo mv -- "$file" "$file.jpg"; done
```

[NOTE: these are 'no ops' until the `n` switch or the `echo` are removed - so you can check the correct replacement before committing]

If you do want to automatically distinguish between jpg and avi files that would also be possible using a more complex loop and the `file` or `mimetype` command

Comment: +1 but note that 1) this will also rename directories and 2) it does not recurse which I think the OP needs since they have "multiple directories".

Comment: Recursion is not important, but it's a good observation. I love the way you built this as a demo-then-true model.

Comment: Thanks but you should look at @terdon's answer as a more general (and more robust) solution.

Comment: @steeldriver You should probably specify which `rename` you are using. This is the one that [comes with perl](http://man.he.net/man1/rename), not the more common and less useful one which [comes with util-linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)

Comment: @BroSlow fair point but the Ubuntu (and Debian) default `rename` is the perl one. The one from `util-linux` is `/usr/bin/rename.ul` on Ubuntu while  `/usr/bin/rename` is by default a symlink to `/usr/bin/prename`. In general in the Debian world (and this is Ask _Ubuntu_) it is safe to assume `prename` unless otherwise stated.

Comment: $ for file in *; do echo mv -- "$file" "$file.csv"; done
did work for me. I wanted to add .csv to all files in my folder. none of them have extension

Answer (score 9):

If you have a more complex hierarchy, you'll need a slightly more sophisticated approach. You can either use bash's [`globstar` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) which lets `**` match  zero or more directories and subdirectories or you can use `find`.

1. globstar

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   for f in **/*; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv "$f" "$f".jpg; done
   ```

   The `[ -f "$f" ] &` ensures that the `mv` command is only run on files and not directories.
2. `find`

   ```
   find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv "{}" "{}".jpg
   ```

   The `-type f` ensures we only find files and no directories and the `print0` causes `find` to print its output separated with the null character (`\0`) instead of newlines. This ensures that we deal correctly with file names containing spaces or newlines or other weirdness.

   `xargs` takes a list of input and runs the command given on it. The `-0` flag tells it to expect null-separated input and the `-I{}` will make it replace each instance of `{}` with each of the input records (files in this case) passed.

Comment: Thank you for showing "The Linux Way." This find method turns out to be quite flexible.

Comment: To make the extension capitalized without appending, using a similar technique, assuming no files are named with a %: `find -name *.jpg -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c "printf \"'{}' \" && printf \"'{}\" | head -c-4 && printf \".JPG'\0\"" | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c "mv {}"`

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to `man rename` before you try this

This should work like a charm.

In a terminal:

```
cd /path/to/exported/imgs/folder/
rename  's/(\w+)$/$1\.jpg/' *
```

Please change "jpg" to whatever you need.

`rename` can use perl expresions.. your best friend

At first line you entered your files directory

```
cd /path/to/exported/imgs/folder/
```

The `s` the before expresion indicates a substitution

```
rename  's/(\w+)$/$1\.jpg/' *
```

Then will search for any file with an alphanumeric and underscore name , but without extension

```
rename  's/(\w+)$/$1\.jpg/' *
```

And replace add to it . a dot jpg

```
rename  's/(\w+)$/$1\.jpg/' *
```

Finally apply to any file in first line folder

```
rename  's/(\w+)$/$1\.jpg/' *
```

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you use a program called `pyrenamer`.

Open it, and in the Renamed file name pattern, enter `{1}.jpg`.

Comment: Very easy and worked like charm

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this situation quite often administering systems, especially when dealing with filenames created by windows applications.  To add `.jpg` extensions on filenames without any extension, consider this command list.

```
find ./example -type f -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' mv '{}' '{}'.jpg
```

find's `-print0` generates NULL characters for separators, xargs's `-0` is for accepting those NULL separators.  This will also do this for any subdirectories, so be sure to  replace that './example'  path.

`rename` is a great command, but it's distro specific in both implementation and specification.  I generally use things like `rename` on the command line, but I always write in GNU utils standards for my scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
rename  's/$/.jpg/' *
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer https://askubuntu.com/a/485537 ?